# AES CMAC generating wrong signature

Tags: python, aes

I'm trying to generate AES-CMAC using cryptography library. And with message and key it is generating different output then online calculator : [AES-CMAC ONLINE CALCULATOR](https://artjomb.github.io/cryptojs-extension/)

Here is my code

```
aeskey_for_CMAC = binascii.hexlify(key[-16:])

c = cmac.CMAC(algorithms.AES(aeskey_for_CMAC))
c.update(message)
Cmac = c.finalize()

print("CMAC : ",binascii.hexlify( Cmac))
```

Here the `key = b'cce9cdc049d9b46140a850dc8c7b146c9efa60caa228c49e1eec9303bed205ba'` and `message = b'6ffad88b23783dc86974c75f87370dc0'`

Output from above code :  `b'dc629809794c584107f4d81cb7133982'`
Output from online calculator/Expected : `dfea87c2 b4c2678a b63241e5 52b84acd`

Can anybody tell me whats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To derive the key `aeskey_for_CMAC`, `key` must not be hex **en**coded, but hex **de**coded and from the result the last 16 bytes are to be used as CMAC key:

```py
aeskey_for_CMAC = binascii.unhexlify(key)[-16:]
```

The message must also be hex decoded:

```py
c.update(binascii.unhexlify(message))
```

With these changes, the code returns the result you are looking for: `dfea87c2b4c2678ab63241e552b84acd`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked well. I was not knowing about this concept.